# ¿Como usar un botón de tipo radio como condicional en HTML?

Tags: html5, radiobutton

Necesito saber como usar un botón de tipo radio como condicional en HTML.

Les explico, tengo una sección dentro de mi código HTML para abrir unas paginas externas a la mia, pero estoy utilizando dos botones de tipo radio para que el usuario indique si quiere que al hacer clic en el hipervinculo, esta página se abra en una pagina nueva o en un elemento iframe.

Les dejo el codigo que tengo para que tengan la referencia

```
<form>
    <label for="iframe">Iframe</label>
    <input type="radio" name="fuentes" id="iframe" value="iframe">
    <label for="blank">Pagina en blanco</label>
    <input type="radio" name="fuentes" id="blank" value="blank">
</form>
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="???">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="???">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="???">Instagram</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/" target="???">Reddit</a></li>
</ul>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" width="800px" height="800px" name="IF"></iframe>
```

Comment: El planteamiento esta claro. Lo que no está tan claro es lo que has probado para conseguir ese comportamiento. Tampoco esta claro si eso lo quieres en javascript o bien lo vas a procesar en un backend en PHP o similar. Tu pregunta carece de un [example] y de errores que podamos ayudarte a depurar. Lo siento pero parece una tarea que encomiendas a alguien en lugar de un problema de programación que tengas (aparte de que quizas no sepas hacerlo, claro, pero tampoco demuestras haberlo intentado, tan solo has realizado un planteamiento). Lo siento, pero aqui no hacemos tareas (o no deberiamos).

Answer (score 1):

Para esto puedes usar JavaScript de la siguiente manera:

###### HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_Male" value="Male" /> 
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_Female" value="Female" />
```

###### JAVASCRIPT

```
if(document.getElementById('gender_Male').checked) {  
// El botón de tipo radio masculino está chequeado
}else if(document.getElementById('gender_Female').checked) {  
// El botón de tipo radio femenino está chequeado
}
```